# Website background images not showing on mobile safari

Tags: html, css, background, mobile-safari

I'm having trouble getting m background images to show on mobile safari. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. Usually if I refresh the page everything shows the way I want, which makes it tricky to test. Always works fine on the desktop browsers I've tried.

Here is the site: https://www.shimmeo.com

I've tried replacing the shorthand background css tags with non-shorthand, as suggested by other answers, and no joy.

TIA!

Comment: this sounds as an issue with loading the picture which takes too much time. How big is the picture for start?

Comment: Could it be that simple? It is a big picture. I will try lowering the resolution and see if that works.

Comment: @keikoku92: Looks like it works. Make it an answer (as opposed to comment) and if it works after more testing, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sounds as an issue with loading the picture which takes too much time. How big is the picture for start?
Hope yhis will help.
Thanks